# How to fix Android Studio bug not showing .xml files properly?

Tags: android, android-studio

Due to some reason, my Android Studio has stopped showing .xml files properly. Here's an example of what I get:

[image]

[image]

I have checked my .xml files by opening the folder using Windows Explorer and opening the files in WordPad. They are all perfectly okay. It's just that Android Studio is displaying in my .xml files what just seems nonsense to me. (By the way, some .xml files are being properly displayed in Android Studio).

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Did you try **Build > Clean Project** ?

Comment: @null_override I just tried it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem.

Make a backup of your app folder.

Open your layout folder (right-click on any .xml file and click 'Show in Explorer'). Close Android Studio. Move (cut) all except one of the files to your desktop (or any other folder). Restart Android Studio. After the gradle sync has finished, move (cut) all the files back to the layout folder. Repeat for the last file.

Do the same if there is a similar problem with your java files.